# Unable to install texlive from install-tl

Tags: installing, texlive

I am unable to install texlive from install-tl script on fedora20.

When I use:

```
./install-tl gui wizard
```

It gives an error:

```
invalid after png_start_read_image or png_read_update_info at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Tk/Image.pm line 21
```

What is missing? How can I get this right?

Comment: Try only `./install-tl`. It is easy and the GUI is not necessary. You can follow the textual instructions.

Comment: isn't it `./install-tl --gui` (note the `--`), remember to make sure that `perl-tk` is installed

Comment: @Sigur I tried that but it appears so confusing in the text mode.Plus, one is not sure one has chosen all things needed.

Supposing I miss out on something, will I be able to install it later?

While we are here, what directory should I install it to? ~/texlive/ as the base directory?

Comment: @daleif perl-tk is installed. And no, it is ./install-tl -gui perltk or ./install-tl -gui wizard

Comment: @deshmukh, yes, you can use `tlmgr` to install packages later. When I install I don't change the directories. I choose the default one suggested by the installer. I just change the schemes to choose the full install.

Comment: @deshmukh, no it does not need an argument (perltk is the default), plus `./install-tl --gui` and `./install-tl -gui` is the same thing. I tend to install in `/opt/texlive` and install as my self not as root

Comment: @daleif yes. you are right re arguments. But I do not have write access to /opt also. So, will need to choose a folder in ~. I was wondering if there is a 'standard' folder in ~ where it is installed

Comment: No it does not matter. But if you do not have access to opt, are you then on s multi user system? Then why not get the sysadmin to install it globally for all users

Comment: @daleif all went well and installation was a sueccess. If you post a reply, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gui installer is called via

```
./install-tl --gui
```

Note the double minus. Actually, you can use only one, I just find it more readable